# Как сохранить результат php скрипта в файл?

Tags: xml, php, синтаксический-анализ

Вопрос в следующем. 
Распарсил я несколько сторонних xml (данные о погоде, которые располагаются на третьей стороне) и преобразовал полученную информацию в нужном мне виде. Если оставить все как есть и отправлять полученную информацию сразу на страницу, то при обновлении уходит много времени - не хорошо! Населенных пунктов много, а обновляется погода 4 раза в сутки.

- Задача №1: как сохранить результат парсинга в php файл, который я прикручу к странице с выводом?
- Задача №2: как самоисполнить этот скрипт в конкретное время 4 раза в сутки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

по первому вопросу - читайте до полного понимания [PHP. Работа с файлами](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=fs&page=005).

по второму вопросу - ответ [cron](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).
Правда на некоторых хостингах крон недоступен, тогда нужно делать классическое кеширование. Вначале проверяем, как давно запрашивались данные, если больше 6 часов назад - обновляем и в файл. И в любом случае потом отдаем данные пользователю.

Comment: спасибо за направление! Все именно так, как вы и сказали. О результатах отпишусь.

Comment: @KoVadim - есть  крон онлайн сервисы.

Comment: @Azat Khanov - посмотрите в сторону функции [file_put_contents][1]

[1]: http://us1.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: хороша функция. спасибо.

Comment: крон-онлайн сервис... да...